# Rails: Devise custom create registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a custom registration in devise, but Its not doing what I'm supposed to.

I'm trying to create new data:

```
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save

      yield resource if block_given?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        if params[:user][:role] == "Proof"
          Proof.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :first_name => params[:user][:first_name], :last_name => params[:user][:last_name])
        end
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

What's custom is this part:

```
    if params[:user][:role] == "Proof"
      Proof.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :first_name => params[:user][:first_name], :last_name => params[:user][:last_name])
    end
```

But for some reason, its not doing what its supposed to. It won't create the new data in my database upon signup. Is this the wrong location where this is supposed to go?

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
              "authenticity_token"=>"3QTVW3x3cnWho5yd6aEMC31iDIDu+IHQClpQao9VBqc=", 
              "user"=>{"first_name"=>"First", 
                       "last_name"=>"Last", 
                       "role"=>"Proof"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `create` action, swap

```
   respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    if params[:user][:role] == "Proof"
      Proof.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :first_name => params[:user][:first_name], :last_name => params[:user][:last_name])
    end
```

To

```
    if params[:user][:role] == "Proof"
      Proof.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :first_name => params[:user][:first_name], :last_name => params[:user][:last_name])
    end
   respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
```

Currently, `Proof` record is not getting created as the code from `if` statement is dead code and is never executed. The method `create` returns when you call `respond_with` method.
Executing the `if` statement before `respond_with` call should resolve your issue.

**UPDATE**

As per the chat session with OP, the `Proof` record was not getting created because of a validation on `custom_url` field. Suggested to change the validation with `on: :update` option.

```
validates :custom_url, uniqueness: true, on: :update
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response! However, it seems like this still doesn't work. Its supposed to work though right? If Its not working per your suggestion, then it has to be something else?

Comment: If its not working then probably `params[:user][:role]` is not being passed. Share the params hash generated upon form submission in the question.

Comment: Let me check the hash. Is there a way to show hash if there's no error? I'm not sure why its voted down. I didn't do that

Comment: No problem. I am not saying you did it. Someone just gave me serial down voting like on my 20+ answers even accepted ones.

Comment: When you submit the form for user registration then you can see the `params` hash generated in the server log. Hope you know where server log is? You can get it either from the terminal where you started `rails server` or from log file located `logs/..` folder

Comment: I edited my post to include my parameters... does it look correct?

Comment: @KirtiThorat Why the serial downvotes on all your answers -_- ? If it is not reversed tomorrow, contact SO team.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Thanks for asking.:) Some haters I believe didn't like my answers. I got them reversed today after reporting yesterday.

Comment: @KirtiThorat, Whoa that's cool  It happens (_jealousy ofc_) :) Don't give a damn about that. Keep answering stuff. Take care !

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Yup.thats true. Sent you a LinkedIn invitation.

Comment: @KirtiThorat, Thanks ! Glad to connect with such talented people like you !!

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Same here.